# How to switch from native app view to webview?

Tags: webview, automation, appium, native, ui-automation

Their is a payment gateway that depends on the third party, now the payment details are open in the web view. so, how to manage web view in the native app and switch context. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. It will work.

```
driver = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
for (String contextName : contextNames) {
    System.out.println(contextName); //prints out something like NATIVE_APP \n WEBVIEW_1
}
driver.context(contextNames.toArray()[1]); // set context to WEBVIEW_1

//do some web testing
String myText = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".green_button")).click();

driver.context("NATIVE_APP");

// do more native testing if we want

driver.quit();
```

Reference: https://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/web/hybrid/